# Python - import error

Tags: python, python-import

I've done what I shouldn't have done and written 4 modules (6 hours or so) without running any tests along the way.

I have a method inside of `/mydir/__init__.py` called `get_hash()`, and a class inside of `/mydir/utils.py` called `SpamClass`.

`/mydir/utils.py` imports `get_hash()` from `/mydir/__init__`.

`/mydir/__init__.py` imports `SpamClass` from `/mydir/utils.py`.

Both the class and the method work fine on their own but for some reason if I try to import `/mydir/`, I get an import error saying `"Cannot import name get_hash"` from `/mydir/__init__.py`.

The only stack trace is the line saying that `__init__.py` imported `SpamClass`. The next line is where the error occurs in in `SpamClass` when trying to import `get_hash`. Why is this?

Comment: You don't import from files, you import from modules and packages. Please clean up your question keeping this in mind.

Comment: Some actual code would also help. The question suggests you're using `from foo import bar` everywhere, but it isn't obvious. That would be one possible reason for the problem, though.

Comment: circular references are never good - foo import from bar and bar import from foo - there has to be a better way to structure this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty easy problem to encounter. What's happening is this that the interpreter evaluates your `__init__.py` file line-by line. When you have the following code:

```
 import mydir.utils
 def get_hash(): return 1
```

The interpreter will suspend processing `__init__.py` at the point of `import mydir.utils` until it has fully executed 'mydir/utils.py' So when utils.py attempts to import get_hash(), it isn't defined because the interpreter hasn't gotten to it's definition yet.

Comment: @Rakis Thanks. You're a genius. I don't know why I didn't think of that. I've read about that before, but this has really stumped me. Modules are only loaded once ever, unless you use the reload function. I'll make the needed changes and try some more. Thanks again.

Comment: Heh, I'm the 'genius' that keeps making that mistake over and over... Mainly because I'm too lazy to follow bobince's excellent advice ;-)

Comment: too funny. You saved me 30 minutes of hair pulling. It's been so long since I learned that and I've not ever used circular references before so, maybe even 60 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

To add to what the others have said, another good approach to avoiding circular import problems is to **avoid** `from module import stuff`.

If you just do standard `import module` at the top of each script, and write `module.stuff` in your functions, then by the time those functions run, the import will have finished and the module members will all be available.

You then also don't have to worry about situations where some modules can update/change one of their members (or have it monkey-patched by a naughty third party). If you'd imported `from` the module, you'd still have your old, out-of-date copy of the member.

Personally, I only use `from`-`import` for simple, dependency-free members that I'm likely to refer to a lot: in particular, symbolic constants.

Comment: +1 Thanks bobince. I've slowly been leaning towards that style of import for more and more things. For one, I think it makes things more clear. If I have a a call to ``get_hash()`` in my code, it brings up the qeustion "Where did that come from?", but if I Have ``mymodule.get_hash()``, you're at least one namespace closer to knowing exactly what that method is and where it's from.

Comment: Yes, I usually prefer that explicitness too.

Answer (score 1):

In absence of more information, I would say you have a circular import that you aren't working around. The simplest, most obvious fix is to not put anything in `mydir/__init__.py` that you want to use from any module *inside* `mydir`. So, move your `get_hash` function to another module inside the `mydir` package, and import that module where you need it.